# How to add row explicitly in a table in angular JS after Nth row?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

How can i insert some custom rows after Nth row is created in angular js.
For example in checklist items there are 10 objects and i have to put two extra rows after sixth row.

```html
<html>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>N/A</th>
      <th>Date Completed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in checklist">
      <td>{{item.taskName}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: do `$scope.push({})` in your controller itself will add one more row

Comment: do you have any plunker example??

Comment: do you wanted to add new record in `checkList` that should should added last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $index variable of ng-repeat directive. like : ->

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>N/A</th>
      <th>Date Completed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in checklist" ng-if="$index<=6">
      <td>{{item.taskName}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in checklist" ng-if="$index>6">
     <td>{{item.taskName}}</td>
     <td>
       <input type="checkbox">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text">
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome Excellent !! that's all i wanted. Thanks alot Sandeep for your response. I just wanted to know how and where to give the ng-if for index, and you explained it very well.

Comment: One small issue... out of 13 row one data row is missing while adding by this method. I am adding only one row..and in iteration of second table after index>6 i can see the repetition in data.

Comment: Never mind..issue got resolved..i used order by in first iteration and forgot to use in second one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for `splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). It can either add or remove items from an array at any given index. You'll want something along the lines of `arrayOfItems.splice(5, 0, addAfter6thItem)`

Comment: Hi Joe...can you explain this in plunker?? How to use this function in angular js.? Thanks for the response

Comment: I believe Sandeep's answer is what you're looking for. I read your question as you were wanting to insert rows into your array, not that you simply wanted to show extra HTML after the Nth row.